# An equation : $(a+ib)x^2-2cx+(a-ib)=0, a,b,c$ are real and non-zero

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I am dealing with a question that asks the condition on real non-zero parameters $a,b,c$ such that the equation
$$(a+ib)x^2-2cx+(a-ib)=0$$
has $(i):$ exactly one real root, $(ii):$ exactly one purely imaginary root, $(iii)$ two real roots. I give here my answers/attempt for a confirmation as the answer to it is not available to me.

(1): Let $x=p$ be the real root then $(a+ib)p^2-2cp+(a-ib)=0 \implies ap^2-2cp+a=0 \& p^2=1.$ By putting $p=\pm 1$, we get $c=\pm a \implies c^2=a^2.$

(2): Let $x=iq$ be the purely imaginary  root then $-(a+ib)q^2-2icq+(a-ib)=0 \implies bq^2+2cq+b=0 \& q^2=1.$ By putting $q=\pm 1$, we get $c=\mp b \implies c^2=b^2.$

(3): Since the sum of the roots of the quadratic is given as $\alpha+\beta=\frac{2c}{a+ib}$.
The sum being complex (non-real) both the roots cannot be real for any condition on the real nonzero parameters $a,b,c$.

Are my answers correct ?

Comment: yes it seems fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\displaystyle (a+ib)x^2-2cx+(a-ib)=0, a,b,c \in R, \ne 0 ~~~(1)$$
Yes your answers and the approach are right, you may verify them using the solutions of the quadratic equation:
$$x=\frac{c\pm \sqrt{c^2-a^2-b^2}}{a+ib}~~~(2)$$
$$c=a \implies x=\frac{a\pm ib}{a+ib}=1,\frac{a-ib}{a+ib}.$$
$$c=-a \implies x=\frac{-a\pm ib}{a+ib}=\frac{-a+ib}{a+ib},-1.$$
Similarly, $$c=b \implies x=\frac{b\pm ia}{a+ib}= \frac{b+1a}{a+ib},-i,$$
$$c=-b \implies x=\frac{-b\pm ia}{a+ib}=i, \frac{-b-ia}{a+ib}.$$

Next, (1) cannot have both roots as real due to Fundamental Theorem of Algebra,
according to which if the coefficient(s) of a polynomial equation is/are complex
(non-real) it will have at least one root complex (non-real).